# Passing string from Angular to API

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I want to fill in one string parameter in my ASP.NET Core MVC API controller via Angular.

I have this working call:

**API**

```
//A class to wrap my string
public class Foo
{
  public string bar { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDetails([FromBody] Foo bar) { ... }
```

**Angular (service)**

```
public get() {
  let bar: any = new Object();
  bar.foo = 'Hello World';

  return this._httpClient.post('api/GetDetails', bar).toPromise();
}
```

But what I really want is pass a string without having to wrap it in a class like  this:

**API**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDetails([FromBody] string bar) { ... }
```

**Angular (service)**

```
public get() {
let bar: string = "Hello World";

return this._httpClient.post('api/GetDetails', bar).toPromise();
}
```

But I get errors like it's an Unsupported Media Type or 'bar' stays null.
What is the right syntax to just pass one value?
The other thing is, I can pass an integer from Angular to the API just fine but not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
let bar = JSON.stringify({'foo' : 'Hello World'});
let body = new HttpParams();
body = body.set('bar', bar);

http.post('/api/GetDetails', body).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways, depending on whether you have control over back or front end.

**1. Angular-service**
Use header `application/json; charset=utf-8` as described [here](https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/) and [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api) (note the charset)

**2. API**
The other one is to build a [custom string-binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) derived which spits out a string.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDetails([ModelBinder(typeof(StringBinder))] string bar) { ... }
```

where

```
public class StringBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            Body = sr.ReadToEnd();


        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(Model);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Agnular 10 the following works:

```
let bar = 'Hello World!';
this._httpClient.post('api/GetDetails', '=' + bar, { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' 
    }) 
})
```

PS: the way I figured it out was by comparing curls generated from dev tools for the working request in AngularJs and not working request in Angular 10