# How to post a string value from Angular 8 to .NET core Web API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I cannot post a simple string value to my WebApi and I get a 415 error.
What's the correct syntax to make this happen?
Thanks!

```js
createRole(name: string) {
    var fullUri = this.baseUri;
    fullUri += 'api/role/CreateRole';

    return this.http.post(fullUri, name);
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost("CreateRole")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoleAsync([FromBody]string name)
{
    //...

}
```

Comment: Is the solution marked as answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239180/passing-string-from-angular-to-api) helpful?

Comment: Yes this ended up working for me but I was hoping to avoid this approach since it's just one single property. Thanks for sharing though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[FromForm]` attribute instead of `[FromBody]` attribute. And apply `[ApiController]` attribute to your controller.

```
[HttpPost("CreateRole")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoleAsync([FromForm]string name)
{
    //...

}
```

It will work if you post `name` as FormData or using Form tag. Because `[FromForm]` gets values from posted form fields.

Another solution is post `name` as object and make a model / DTO

```
public class SaveModel 
{
   public string Role {get; set;}
}
[HttpPost("CreateRole")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoleAsync([FromBody] SaveModel model)
{
    //...

}
```

Comment: ```name``` comes in as ```null``` when I use [FromForm]

Comment: @roonz11 I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes I ended up wrapping my string property in a DTO to get it to work but I was hoping to not have to do this since it's just one single property.
How would I modify my code to post it as FormData?
Thanks!

Comment: In your method change to `createRole() {
    var fullUri = this.baseUri;
    fullUri += 'api/role/CreateRole';
   var formData: any = new FormData();
   var role = "test";
  formData.append("name", role);
  return this.http.post(fullUri, formData);
}`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This approach worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FromForm as @4L4M1N's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284677/10026099) like this

Angular :

```
createRole(name: string) {
    var fullUri = this.baseUri;
    fullUri += 'api/role/CreateRole';
    
var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("name",name)

    return this.http.post(fullUri, name);
}
```

C# :

```
[HttpPost("CreateRole")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoleAsync([FromForm]string name)
{
    //...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

A little tweak in api

```
 [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/role/CreateRole")]
            public int Post([FromBody] string name)
            {
               //logic...
            }
```